# Elasticsearch -> Search on index with different types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Created Elasticsearch Index and under this index, I have stored 3-4 types. Now I want to search on index and want to give preference/score/boost for types. Means when I search on index, want to search on specific types first and then on other types.

Suppose, there are company index - user, accessories are types under company.
So, when I search on company index firstly i want to search in user type and then into accessories. Is there any way in elasticsearch so can I apply preference in query?

Also I want to apply pagination to result thats why I don't want to query separately on type search. I am doing this without tire.

Any solution?

Comment: Any reasons for not using something like tire? Looks to me that you could benefit from it.

Comment: No specific reason. Using rest-api calls directly.

Comment: You can use custom score queries or implement a script for your score. Both influence the order in which results are retrieved. Pagination is done through `from` and `size` parameters.